# I want to get 1 line from a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a PS1 script that reads a cmd file to get a few values and put them in a variable.
These values are commands and I want to be able to run them one by one.
Goal is to put that script in an App-V sequence and because the Application support of that application needs to update the CMD file regularly, I need this constuction.

What I have is:

```
$Sysvar = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"} 

$Sysvar = $SysVar -replace ";",''

ForEach($Var in $SysVar) {
  $Var
}
```

(What is does is it Searches in the CMD file for remarked entries (these are the commands I need, but the are remarked so they wont interfere with the current production)

Than I replace the remark with nothing.
Now I have 3 lines and I need to run them one by one. I was hoping to accomplish this with ForEach but here I got stuck.

I am kind of a noob with Powershell and I am not a developer but a system engineer/Packager so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `$var` -> `cmd /c $var`?

Comment: `$var | select-object -first 1`?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  You simply need to tell PowerShell that you want to execute the contents of `$var` via `cmd.exe` using the `&` operator.

```
ForEach($Var in $SysVar) {
  & cmd /c $Var
}
```

I suggest putting quotation marks around `$Var` to avoid problems with spaces:

```
ForEach($Var in $SysVar) {
  & cmd /c "`"$Var`""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want

```
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"}
for($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++)
{
  & cmd /c "$var[$i]"
}
```

or like you did with `foreach`:

```
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"} | select-object -first 3
ForEach($line in $var) 
{
  & cmd /c "$line"
}
```

In `get-content` varaibles, you can also access each line with the array operators like `$var[number]` so if you want to get the first 3 lines only, there are two good ways imo.

1. You can use the for loop. In my first example, the for loop loops through the first 3 lines (`$i -lt 3`) and then `cmd /c`'s each line.

and

2. You can define the `get-content` with also `select-object` so you can take the first 3 lines with the `-first` switch. Then you can loop through the first three lines like you did with `foreach` in your question.

and if you want to run the whole script, just remove the `select-object` or change `$i -lt 3` to `$i -lt $var.length` like so:

```
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"}
for($i = 0; $i -lt $var.length; $i++)
{
  & cmd /c "$var[$i]"
}
```

or

```
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"}
ForEach($line in $var) 
{
  & cmd /c "$line"
}
```

And if you want one specific line

```
#third line
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"} | `
Select-object -first 3 | Select-Object -skip 2
ForEach($line in $var) 
{
  & cmd /c "$line"
}
```

or

```
#third line
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"}
for($i = 2; $i -lt 3; $i++)
{
  & cmd /c "$var[$i]"
}
```

or simply:

```
#third line
$var = Get-Content C:\Powershell\run.cmd | Where-Object {$_ -Match ";"}
& cmd /c "$var[2]"
```

Comment: Thank you Neko, I will play with this, because the other solution did help me run the complete variable, but I think your solution will provide me with the line for line execution.